# Como copiar conteúdo de uma div para um input?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando copiar conteúdo de uma div para um input. Eu já consegui copiar de um input para outro ou de uma div para outra, mas não consegui de uma div para um input.

```
<div id="teste">
  Exemplo
</div>
<input id="texto" />
```

O que eu consegui foi :

```
<div id="teste">
  Exemplo dasjkhd kdhasj khd askjh
</div>
<div id="texto"></div>

<script>// Elemento com o Texto
var elemento = document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML;
// Escrevendo em outro Elemento
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
texto.innerHTML = "Texto Copiado: " + elemento;
</script>
```

Comment: input não tem a propriedade `innerHTML`, tente usar a propriedade `value`, aliás, coloque o tipo do input, text, por exemplo

Comment: Deu certo, agora teria como atualizar automaticamente sem precisar atualizar a pagina?

Comment: pode colocar o script no evento `onchange` do div

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deu certo, agora teria como atualizar automaticamente, sem precisar
>   atualizar a pagina? pois esta div se transforma em um textarea

Você pode adicionar um [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) que observa as modificações no elemento e atualizar o conteudo do input:

```js
// Elemento com o Texto
var elemento = document.getElementById('teste');
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
  elemento.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  var elemento = this.innerHTML;
  // Escrevendo em outro Elemento
  texto.value = "Texto Copiado: " + elemento;
})
```

```html
<div id="teste" contentEditable="true" style="height:50px; border: 1px dashed #ccc; margin: 5px 0">
  CLIQUE PARA EDITAR O TEXTO
</div>
<input id="texto" />
```

**EDIT:**

Vi que esse método está "deprecated", existem outras opções, uma delas é alterar o nome do listener de `DOMSubtreeModified` para `input`

```js
// Elemento com o Texto
var elemento = document.getElementById('teste');
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
  elemento.addEventListener('input', function () {
  var elemento = this.innerHTML;
  // Escrevendo em outro Elemento
  texto.value = "Texto Copiado: " + elemento;
})
```

```html
<div id="teste" contentEditable="true" style="height:50px; border: 1px dashed #ccc; margin: 5px 0">
  CLIQUE PARA EDITAR O TEXTO
</div>
<input id="texto" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Elemento com o Texto
var elemento = document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML;
// Escrevendo em outro Elemento
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
texto.value = "Texto Copiado: " + elemento;
```

```html
<div id="teste">
  Exemplo
</div>
<input id="texto" />
```

Comment: Deu certo, agora teria como atualizar automaticamente, sem precisar atualizar a pagina? pois esta div se transforma em um textarea